# Invalid Javascript left hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

Wondering why I'm getting invalid left hand side assignment. Doesn't my for loop iterate through the array of string characters, get its numeric value (ASCII) and add it to count and re-assign it to the variable?

```
function getCharNumber(string1, string2) {
  let count1 = 0
  let count2 = 0
  let strArray1 = string1.split('')
  let strArray2 = string2.split('')
  for (let i = 0; i < strArray1.length; i++) {
    strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0) += count1
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <strArray2.length; i++) {
    strArray2[i].charCodeAt(0) += count2
  }
  console.log(count1, count2)
}
```

Comment: What do you intend `strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0) += count1` to do? You can't modify strings if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: BTW, `strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0)` can be simplified to `string1.charCodeAt(i)`. There's no need to split the string into an array, since `charCodeAt()` can index the string.

Comment: The answer to your question is: [JavaScript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type) are immutable, and your code is trying to mutate a string. Not sure what your code is trying to achieve though. Is it "encrypting" the original strings by "shifting" each of its characters? Is it counting the number of characters in each input string/

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order at call to `String.prototype.charCodeAt()`. Assign the result of the call to `count1`, `count2`

```
for (let i = 0; i < strArray1.length; i++) {
    count1 += strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0);
}
for (let i = 0; i <strArray2.length; i++) {
    count2 += strArray2[i].charCodeAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error, like others have stated, because you're trying to assign a value to a number.

```
strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0) += count1
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
12 += count1
```

That doesn't work b/c you can't assign anything to the number `12`. Instead, you need to increment directly

```
strArray1[i] =  String.fromCharCode(strArray1[i].charCodeAt(0) + count1)
```